What should I do to add a correction for an already submitted article?
If I need to make a correction to the results of a paper but I already submitted the proofs for publication, what should I do? What is the impact of such a correction for the authors? I got an email of the proof with the DOI awaiting confirmation.
I got a response
Given that your manuscript has already been exported from our manuscript handling system, in order to facilitate further peer review, the latest version of your work will need to be submitted again as a new manuscript, accompanied by a cover letter explaining the changes. If you have already paid the article processing charge, this would be refunded.
As the article was accepted for publication, it is exported from the editorial system and forwarded to production. However, once the export has happened, no changes can be made on the editorial system.
Does it mean that the old one will be published now and after sending the modifications it will updated ?
I'm afraid that the message mean that and ask again but hope someone help me

Sorry your English is pretty hard to understand. The paper is already published and you want to make a correction?

sorry for that. No, I'm waiting the confirmation for publishing. i sent the proof already

I have done it. At first, they said that no changes can be made, but, in the end, they made the correction.

Thanks for replying , please Does the paper published with the corrections without any note with it ?

I think we all misunderstood your earlier question, thinking you were writing about a general proofreading service, rather than a submission. But the answer there would be, once again, to ask the editor. Good luck.

I sent the message now and hope i got positive reaction. Thanks again @Buffy

Is your paper submitted or nearly published? The text says "submitted", but you also mention a DOI, which strongly suggests that it is nearly published.

@Allure i updated the post please can you check it

@Sursula i updated the post please can you check it

Your description does not make sense. I already submitted the proofs for publication suggests that your paper is not only accepted, it has already gone through production. But the response you got says further peer review is needed. Something is incorrect. Make sure your description is accurate.

That what happened to me in my case. The paper already gone to the production and i sent to the editor and his reply as i post

If your paper really has gone through production and then needs to go through peer review, I cannot answer the question because I don't know what the answer is. If (much more likely imo) your description is inaccurate, then look at https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a carefully and amend the question as necessary.

Inform the editor immediately. It may cause a delay but will prevent later problems.
Don’t wait.
Depending on the nature of the error a quick fix might be possible. Or not.

How the cycle will go in both if it will be fix or not please

The editor will know. Ask.

can i withdraw it after proof ?

Again, ask the editor.

thanks but i ask here if someone met this issue before

Every case will be different and so don't give you any guidance. Ask the editor. Please. Just. Do. It.

i will do of course as it is unintended mistake

@Begnnier it is in the interest of the editor to publish error free articles, so I don't think that anyone will object to you asking

@Sursula Thanks a lot. it is the first time to face this issue and honestly afraid from any reaction
